# Implement Tag database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Well hi everyone I'm kinda new on Asp.net Mvc, and need some help to improve, in my project that I'm working at, I need to register a user and in the register the user must choose some tags that are categories related to the subject of my website, the thing is that i have a database that looks like this

**Tag**

```
public int TagId{get;set;}
public string TagName{get;set;}
public string TagColor{get;set;}
```

**TagUser**

```
public int TagUserId{get;set;}
public int UserId{get;set;}
```

I read that EF constructs the tables when there is a many to many relationship, it construct the middle table automatically so in my case do i just need to have the first model and my user model? or should i use the 2 models above plus the user model, with the second approach i don't know how to relate de data i can define the TagUserId as primary key and UserId as foreignkey and relate the tables, but do i need this? or can i do that with the first approach if someone can give me a tip i appreciate a lot. :)

Ps: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a `Tags` property of type `IList<Tag>` in your `User` class and a `Users` property in your `Tag` class of type `IList<User>`. Entity Framework  will create a third table to store the many to many association between `Tag` and `User`.

```
public class Tag
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string TagName {set;get;}
   public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string UserName {set;get;}
   public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i just have 1 problem, my user table is the default user table, how can i scaffold it so i have the tags on register?

Comment: Search for "extend Identity User table" and you will get a ton of samples.